# Is there a way to "pause" the `appshot()` function to allow Shiny App to fully render before running?

Tags: r, shiny, webshot

### Context

I am working on a R package (called [`mapBliss`](https://github.com/benyamindsmith/mapBliss)) for making custom souvenir style maps which utilizes `leaflet` and the Mapbox-API.

Thanks to the help of SO I managed to figure out [how to create a picture frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74708437/putting-a-leaflet-map-in-a-picture-frame-in-r) by using utilizing `shiny` and `css`.

### My Question

I am looking to figure out how to take a screenshot of the picture that I made with the `webshot` package's `appshot()` function but for some reason I am unable to get it to capture the picture as I want it.

For the example, the code I am running produces the following (Shiny App) output:

```r
# devtools::install_github("benyamindsmith/mapBliss")
library(mapBliss)

map<-plot_city_view("Jersalem, IL") |>
            frame_1(title_text="Jerusalem", 
                    subtitle_text="City of Gold", 
                    subtitle_font="Brush Script MT") 

map
```

[image]

If I want to capture the output using `appshot()` I get the following output:

```r
library(webshot)

map |> appshot()
```

[image]

I assume its because `appshot()` is taking the screenshot before the shiny app fully renders. Is there a way to "delay" `appshot()` or is there another workaround?

Comment: Haven't tried, but according to the docs, you have to `appshot` the app. You should be able to do that by a) supplying a path to the single-file app/app directory or b) an app object, *not* by capturing an object from within app. You can both supply a `timout` and a `delay` argument: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/webshot/versions/0.5.4/topics/appshot . Nifty app, by the way :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with the `vheight` and `delay` parameters.

```r
 plot_city_view("Jersalem, IL") |>
frame_1(title_text="Jerusalem", subtitle_text="City of Gold", subtitle_font="Brush Script MT") |> 
appshot(vheight = 1000, delay=10)
```